# Concatenate subsequent cells in a column - excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help me to solve the below problem using VBA?

I want to concatenate cells A7, A8, B8, A9 and paste it to A7. Similarly concatenate A10, A11, A12, C12, A13, A14 and paste to A10. Concatenate A15, A16 and paste to A15. Keep A6 same and A17 same as original value.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
[worksheet sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0xe2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    [A7] = [A7] & [A8] & [B8] & [A9]
    [A10] = [A10] & [A11] & [A12] & [C12] * [A13] & [A14]
    [A15] = [A15] & [A16]
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.

I have around 90 sheets where the cell address changes. Example row number 7 might be blank in some sheets. It is not possible to hardcode the cell positions. Looking for a dynamic solution.